# transfer BIM 360 project between hubs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

is there an easy way to transfer BIM 360 project between hubs? either manually or via Forge.
what I mean transfer project is everything, not just files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you meant by clone projects from one hub to another hub.
There is not manual or direct API way yet.

For the general configurations (members, activate services, folder permissions etc), the Setup tool might be of help.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool

As to transferring files, you may check if the 3rd party app of Forge could be help or not:
https://apps.autodesk.com/BIM360/en/Detail/Index?id=6253626418897534668
or you may have to build a script to transfer. Two samples might be useful:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage
this sample transfers files between cloud storages (google drive, box etc) with BIM360, you could follow the similar format to read files from BIM360 hub, and take advantage of the code to upload to the other hub folder.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-upgradefiles-revit
this sample is to upgrade Revit model version, while the workflow is to get source model from one folder, and upload the output model to the target folder. you could borrow the workflow to copy model from source hub folder to target hub folder.